# Converting PHP site to Joomla. Is it possible?

Tags: php

Alright so we have a client who has a site that he'd like to be able to turn into a Joomla site so that he can make changes to his products. Only problem is, the site is php. Is it possible to convert this site into a joomla site and if so, what is the process in doing that? Or is there any sources I could look at?

I've converted html sites before but the way this site was built makes it a little confusing for me, especially with all of the 'includes' implemented in here. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

**Website:** www.freedomcreativesolutions.com/lighthouse

**Problem:** Unsure if php site can be converted into a joomla site

Here is the code for the front page:

```
 <?php include('inc/default.php'); 

$pageDisc = "Welcome to Lighthouse Solar Solutions & Generators";   
$pageKeys = "Lighthouse solar, lighthouse, solar power, solar panel, solar solutions, generators";
$pageTitle = "Lighthouse Solar | Home";
$slideshow = "on";


?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<?php include('inc/head.php'); ?>

<body>
<?php include('inc/header.php'); ?>

<?php 

  if($slideshow == "on")    { 

      include('inc/slideshow.php');

    }  else {

        include('inc/headbar.php');

        }

?>

<section id="main">

  <div class="wrapper">

    <?php include('inc/triple.php'); ?>

    <!--<div id="fullContent">-->

        <div id="content" class="col8" style="padding-right:75px;">

            <h3>WHO WE ARE &amp; WHAT WE DO.</h3><br>
            <p>Lighthouse offers innovative solar power and standby generator solutions for Piedmont Triad and across North Carolina. We are committed to helping businesses and families find permanent, energy-saving solar solutions that will not only save them money, but also give they a piece of mind about their power availability.  With the rising cost of energy and growing importance of sustainable living, making the decision to switch to solar is easier than ever.<br><br>

            <img src="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>img/nc_solar.png" style="float:right; padding-left:4%; width:30%;">

            As the fastest growing solar power company in Winston-Salem, Lighthouse Solar Solutions provides unmatched service and top-quality solar and standby generator systems. Our professional installation team will get you set up with your solar PV, solar pool heating, solar hot water, and backup power system in no time. With our dedication to quality service, competitive installation pricing and financing options, you’re sure to get the greatest value for your investment.<br><br>

            Our goal at Lighthouse Solar is to provide clean, renewable solar energy at an affordable price.

            </p><br><br>

            <h4>Why Go Solar?</h4><br>

            <p>
            Lighthouse Solar Solutions energy specialists will explain the many advantages of solar power and help you find smart solar solutions that can significantly reduce or eliminate your energy bill without having to change the way you live. You will have peace of mind knowing that you have energy independence and stable, predictable utility costs that last a lifetime. In addition to the great savings you’ll experience by switching to solar, our planet will benefit from cleaner air and increased renewable energy sources.

            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="rightSide" class="col4 last">

            <h3>REFER A FRIEND</h3><br>
            <p>Make the world even greener and get paid!  Now, if you refer a friend who makes a qualified purchase. We will send you a $250 gift card!<br>
            <a class="greenButton">CONTACT US FOR DETAILS</a>
            </p><br>

            <hr><br>
            <h3>CONTACT US</h3><br>
            <p>
            <strong>Lighthouse Solar Solutions <br>&amp; Standby Generators</strong><br><br>
            P.O. Box 11942<br>
            Winston-Salem, NC 27116<br><br>
            <strong>Phone: </strong>336-407-8121<br>
            <strong>Email: </strong>Alighthouse@surry.net<br>
            </p>
            <br>



        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>


   <!-- </div>-->



  </div><!--wrapper-->


</section>







<?php include('inc/footer.php'); ?>

<?php include('inc/scripts.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joomla is based on PHP, so not only is it possible, it's easy. However, it's impossible to answer your question because it depends on how the old site is written. Typically, if it's just a brochure site with a set of static pages (which it seems to be), you can just create Joomla articles to show these content.

What you'll need is a Joomla template that looks similar to the old site, and there are countless out there. The individual "blocks" on the link you gave are the equivalent of modules in Joomla. You can create custom HTML modules and simply paste the content of each block into them.

Comment: So I'd basically do the exact same thing I would do with an html site. So for instance if I wanted to place <jdoc:include type="head"> in this particular file, I would just place it underneath the <?php include('inc/head.php'); ?> tag?

Comment: No. It will be much easier to install a vanilla Joomla site, install a Joomla template that looks similar to the old site, then create the individual modules and content pages manually. The template would've already included all the necessary jdoc tags.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help. I appreciate it!